# Реализовать веб-сервис на базе django, предоставляющий REST-api

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Принимать из POST-запроса .csv файлы для дальнейшей обработки;

Обрабатывать типовые deals.csv файлы, содержащие истории сделок;

Сохранять извлеченные из файла данные в БД проекта;

Возвращать обработанные данные в ответе на GET-запрос.

Требования
Данные хранятся в реляционной БД, взаимодействие с ней осуществляется посредством django ORM.

Ранее загруженные версии файла deals.csv не должны влиять на результат обработки новых.

Эндпоинты соответствуют спецификации:

Выдача обработанных данных
Метод: GET

В ответе содержится поле “response” со списком из 5 клиентов, потративших наибольшую сумму за весь период.

Каждый клиент описывается следующими полями:
username - логин клиента;
spent_money - сумма потраченных средств за весь период;
gems - список из названий камней, которые купили как минимум двое из списка "5 клиентов, потративших наибольшую сумму за весь период", и данный клиент является одним из этих покупателей.

Загрузка файла для обработки
Метод: POST

Аргументы:
deals: файл, содержащий историю сделок.

Ответ:
Status: OK - файл был обработан без ошибок;
Status: Error, Desc: <Описание ошибки> - в процессе обработки файла произошла ошибка.

Приложение должно быть контейнирезировано при помощи docker;

Проект не использует глобальных зависимостей за исключением:  python, docker, docker-compose;

Readme проекта описывает весь процесс установки, запуска и работы с сервисом;

Требования к фронтенду не предъявляются, интерфейс взаимодействия — RestFull API;

Проект запускается одной командой.

Comment: осталось только ценник предложить и я уверен найдутся желающие реализовать это для тебя. Только мне кажется ты сайтом ошибся.

Comment: @AndreyMaslov Если бы ошибся - написал куда надо было,но тут торопился и неправильно установил вопрос,а звучит следующим образом:реализовал приложение для загрузки csv файла,но данные сохраняются в текстовый файл,а нужно в БД - ищу выход из ситуации. Далее вторая часть: сделать GET запрос - тут ломал голову как реализовать и пришел к выводу,что делается так:
1)SELECT sum(t) AS st, customer FROM deals GROUP BY customer ORDER BY st desc;
2)SELECT customer, item FROM deals WHERE customer in (customer_list)
Первая сортирует по убывающей из таблицы по покупателям,а второй уже производит выборку.

Comment: @AndreyMaslov Короче,мне только приложение написать и может кто-нибудь предложит как это сделать лучше и запросы прикрепить и триггеры установить.